# How can I handle and operate Div pop-up and tabs inside it using Selenium

Tags: selenium, popup, selenium-ide

I am trying to operate div pop-up to automate my project but don't know how to do it. Below is the image of the module I am working on. Also, can  anyone tell me how  can I handle the tabs inside a pop-up.https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7VDx.png